# My Camera intent kills fragment when returning

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, android-10.0

Since I updated my Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.1 (2019) 2Gb to android 10 , my camera intent restarts my app/kill my fragment when returning the photo.
The problem is inconsistent, sometimes I can take 10 photos without a problem, as the application restarts with 1 photo.

I wonder if someone has already encountered the same problem and if they managed to find a solution.

This is where I start the camera intent

```java
File imageDirectory = new File(user.getImageCacheDirectoryPath() + "/pole/" + pole.getId() + "/");      

if (!imageDirectory.exists())
    imageDirectory.mkdirs();

String fname = "/photo_" + foto + "_pre.jpg";
tempImageFile = new File(imageDirectory + fname);

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

if (tempImageFile.exists()) {
    tempImageFile.delete();
}

mImageCaptureUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", tempImageFile);
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
        mImageCaptureUri);
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
        String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        getActivity().grantUriPermission(packageName, mImageCaptureUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    }
}

startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

And this in onActivityResult.

Note: the debugger never reaches this.

```java
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode){
                case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
                    try {
                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inSampleSize = 2;

                        InputStream input = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(mImageCaptureUri);
                        Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);
                        imageBitmap = Utils.rotateImageIfRequired(imageBitmap, tempImageFile.getPath());
                        imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, 1100, 1400, true);
                        saveImage(imageBitmap);

                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: _"my camera intent restarts my app/kill my fragment"_ - This usually indicates that your app has crashed. Plug in your device and try to replicate the issue again, then post your crash log here

Comment: @user3170251 https://pastebin.com/AuwrSReu here is the run log. the E/CustomCameraError mark the start of the camera intent. theres no crash the device returns to my mainActivity killing the fragment i was before.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected trough the Activity lifecycle, Android may kill the backstack activity if it wish to and try to reconstruct it from onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState, if you implement both of those you can safely avoid the lost and restore of state